# include(locate_template) messing up the loop

Tags: loop, themes

So, I've developed a one page theme that pulls in child pages of the parent in order create the layout. I also have it set up to pull each sub pages page template and display the content accordingly, like so.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Page- Home */
get_header(); ?>

<?php 
  $this_page=get_query_var('page_id');
  $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => $this_page, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
  $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
?>

  <?php include(locate_template($template)); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This works perfectly on the homepage, but I'm running into a problem trying to create another parent page with the same template for the company information. As I said, I have the same code in this new template, but something has gotten messed up, and in the About page, it only displays from the `<head>` section to the end of my `<header>`. The footer and beyond doesn't display. What I've found though is that I can comment out the include and it works perfectly.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem here. It was with the `$this_page` variable, it was referencing the homepage still and kept the about page from working. I had to simply modify how it was pulling the page ID and storing it.

Here's my amended code.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Page- Home */
get_header(); ?>

<?php 
  $this_page=get_the_ID();
  $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'page', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => $this_page, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC') ); 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
  $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
?>  

  <?php include(locate_template(array($template), false, true)); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```