# How to get custom page template being edited in gutenberg editor

Tags: customization, pages, templates, admin, block-editor

I want to know custom page template name (the one chosen in page attributes - template) in PHP, before page opens in order to enqueue additional scripts according to chosen template.
I know how to get this information in javascript admin frontend part, however it would be more convenient if I could get it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code once set page template for specific post. If the template isn't set, you cant enqueue your script.

```
if ( $post->_wp_page_template === 'sky-template.php' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script();
}
```

Remember to replace sky-template.php with your template file name.

**Edit:**

You can get some help from this question.
[_wp_page_template to dynamically use template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227435/wp-page-template-to-dynamically-use-template)

Comment: Thank you for effort. However, $post is not available outside the loop. I wrote I want to know the value of template in admin screen, while editing page. Suppose template is already set and we are now editing page which was created earlier.